# Tibco RendezVous messages content log

Tags: tibco-rv

I would like to know if there is way to log tibco RV messages content ? I need to know when a particular message was received. Also, where is the current log page pointing to? Are there log files ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Messages aren't logged by daemons, no.  But you can write a simple script that does a tibrvlisten on the desired subject and writes that to a file

```
tibrvlisten -service 7601 -network ;230.1.1.1;230.1.1.1 "FOO.>" > foobar.txt
```